XML configuration of AnyChart Gantt Resource chart
At this moment I’m working on an application in Oracle APEX, and in some of its pages I need to draw some Gantt charts with the help of AnyChart library (Gantt chart regions in Oracle APEX don’t meet the requirements for the task I’m doing) and using the data from XML files.
I’ve managed to make XML file for Gantt Project chart type, and it works well. Here is an example I've got from AnyChart documentation (I've edited it a little bit because it contained some errors):


anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    var xml =
            '<anychart xmlns="https://cdn.anychart.com/schemas/8.4.0/xml-schema.xsd">'+
            '<gantt type="gantt-project">'+
            '<controller>'+
            '<tree_data>'+
            '<children>'+
            '<data_item>'+
            '<tree_data_item_data id="1" name="Activities" actual_start="1169683200000" actual_end="1173830400000"/>'+
            '<children>'+
            '<data_item>'+
            '<tree_data_item_data id="2" name="Draft plan" actual_start="1169683200000" actual_end="1170460800000"/>'+
            '</data_item>'+
            '<data_item>'+
            '<tree_data_item_data id="3" name="Board meeting" actual_start="1170547200000" actual_end="1170547200000"/>'+
            '</data_item>'+
            '<data_item>'+
            '<tree_data_item_data id="4" name="Research option" actual_start="1170547200000" actual_end="1172275200000"/>'+
            '</data_item>'+
            '<data_item>'+
            '<tree_data_item_data id="5" name="Final plan" actual_start="1172275200000" actual_end="1173830400000"/>'+
            '</data_item>'+
            '</children>'+
            '</data_item>'+
            '</children>'+
            '</tree_data>'+
            '</controller>'+
            '</gantt>'+
            '</anychart>';

    var chart = anychart.fromXml(xml);

    // set container id for the chart
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();

});
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="ac:name" content="GANTT JXC 03"/>
    <meta name="ac:short-desc" content=""/>
    <meta name="ac:desc" content=""/>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-gantt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    
    <style>
        html, body, #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>



But when I try to execute this code for XML file for Gantt Resource chart, I do get the chart, but only with its tree on the left and without any period:


anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    var xml =
            '<anychart xmlns="https://cdn.anychart.com/schemas/8.4.0/xml-schema.xsd">' +
            '<gantt type="gantt-resource">' +
            '<controller>' +
            '<tree_data>' +
            '<children>' +
            '<data_item>' +
            '<tree_data_item_data id="409" name="office 404"/>' +
            '<children>' +
            '<data_item>' +
            '<tree_data_item_data id="2" name="Server 2" parent="409"/>' +
            '</data_item>' +
            '</children>' +
            '</data_item>' +
            '</children>' +
            '</tree_data>' +
            '</controller>' +
            '<timeline>' +
            '<periods fill="#FF0000" position="1703030400000" offset="1706140800000">' +
            '<rendering>' +
            '<shapes>' +
            '<shape id="2_1" parent="2" name="shape_1" shape_type="rectangular"/>' +
            '</shapes>' +
            '</rendering>' +
            '</periods>' +
            '</timeline>' +
            '</gantt>' +
            '</anychart>';

    var chart = anychart.fromXml(xml);

    // set container id for the chart
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();

});
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="ac:name" content="GANTT JXC 03"/>
    <meta name="ac:short-desc" content=""/>
    <meta name="ac:desc" content=""/>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-gantt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.4.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    
    <style>
        html, body, #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>



I understand how to make Gantt Resource chart from the data contained in the array (var data = […] etc.), but I need to obtain data from the XML file. I read the xsd file mentioned in the attribute “xmlns” of the “anychart” element, but I haven’t got a clue how to create periods element and its children correctly. Also I’ve tried to save the correctly drawn Gantt Resource chart with the help of function saveToXml of the Chart object, but it didn’t work for me. Moreover, I haven’t found any example for XML configuration of Gantt Resource chart.
So, the question is: how should I edit the XML file for Gantt Resource chart to make AnyChart show the periods?
The version of Oracle APEX is 4.2.6.00.03, the version of AnyChart is 8.4.0.
P.S. I know that 4.2 version of Oracle APEX is very old, but, unfortunately, I have to work with exactly this version.

The issue with the XML code arises from the use of rendering and shapes elements, which are unnecessary for defining periods in a Gantt chart. Instead, utilizing the start, end, actual_start, and actual_end parameters is the correct approach for specifying the timeline of tasks.
Here’s the updated XML data that should function correctly:
    var xml =
        '<anychart xmlns="https://cdn.anychart.com/schemas/8.4.0/xml-schema.xsd">' +
        '<gantt type="gantt-resource">' +
        '<controller>' +
        '<tree_data>' +
        '<children>' +
        '<data_item>' +
        '<tree_data_item_data id="409" name="office 404"/>' +
        '<children>' +
        '<data_item>' +
        '<tree_data_item_data id="2" name="Server 2" parent="409" actual_start="3 Sep 2024" actual_end="4 Sep 2024"/>' +
        '</data_item>' +
        '</children>' +
        '</data_item>' +
        '</children>' +
        '</tree_data>' +
        '</controller>' +
        '<timeline>' +
        '<periods>' +
        '<period fill="#FF0000" start="3 Sep 2024" end="4 Sep 2024" item_id="2"/>' +
        '</periods>' +
        '</timeline>' +
        '</gantt>' +
        '</anychart>';

Feel free to explore the updated Playground Demo showcasing a Gantt Chart using XML data.
